# Simple Central Storage for HA mail server

Tags: storage, nfs, storage-area-network, redundancy

I will have 2 Postfix servers. One will be a backup of the other.

What is the easiest method to provide central storage to both of these boxes? My infrastructure is very simple: Just a lot of Xen hosts, so there is no SAN or anything.

Each Xen host does have RAID1 though.

I don't mind mounting NFS shares on each of those mail servers, as long as the NFS server wasn't a single point of failure. Is there such a thing as redundant NFS?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an idea to have a look at setting up DRBD with NFS. At it's most basic think of DRBD as RAID 1 across two machines, however you can only read and write to one machine. You can then use heartbeat or similar to make sure that only one DRBD node is handling NFS at a time.

This is a gross simplification, but there's plenty of documentation on how to setup DRBD with NFS online.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.tutorialsconnect.com/2009/01/how-to-setup-a-redundant-nfs-server-with-drbd-and-heartbeat-in-centos-5/

Comment: Exactly. Make sure to test the hard way (what happens if I pull the power on one side etc.) before you put it live, and learn how to cure DRBD split brain early on, and it should give you good redundancy on the NFS.